# Enabling/disabling control based on values of more than one control in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Can I control the enabling/disabling of my textbox using a checkbox and a radio-button, both?

My UI is such that the checkbox controls the individual textbox state, while a radio button controls the enable/disable states of both the textbox and the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this in the UI using a multibinding. This would look like this:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiConverter}">
      <Binding ElementName="MyCheckBox" Path="IsChecked" />
      <Binding ElementName="MyRadioButton" Path="IsChecked" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.IsEnabled>
</TextBlock>

<CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioButton"/>
```

Where the converter looks at the checked state of the radio and checkbox

```
public class MultiConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    bool isCheckBoxChecked = (bool)value[0];
    bool isRadioButtonChecked = (bool)value[1];
    return isCheckBoxChecked  && isRadioButtonChecked;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter,
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I just had to add an extra line for declaring that StaticResource MultiConverter in Windows.Resources.